# RDLC Leading Zero's

Tags: c#, rdlc

I'm using RDLC, I'm new in coding and this is my first time encountering RDLC.

The code in RDLC shows [ 0-1 ]
and the expression/value of the current textbox is.
="0-" & First(Fields!no.Value, "DataSet1")

I would like to know, how to add leading zeros in 1 which is no.value

8 Length

I would like to get result is 0-00000001
If the number got 2 length the result must be 0-00000011

Something like this, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
="0-" & First(Fields!no.Value, "DataSet1").ToString("00000000")
```